# ANDROID : Iptables blocking of incomming connections

Tags: android, connection, iptables

I want to block all incoming connections with `iptables` on my android device. I know that  Google apps, like play store, etc. Need some incoming connections (f.e. for GTalkSerivice) and they will be not running after blocking. But I want just use my browser and so I know browser doesn't need incoming connections. So I tried to block all incoming connections with:

```
iptables -A INPUT --j DROP
```

The problem is now, that all of connections are blocked and my browser is also off-line. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, iptables doesn't block connections, but packets. What you've done is block all incoming packets, so it's normal that you get no response. You need to add something like this to let packets form already established connections (ones you have initiated by opening a web page, etc.) through:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Blocking all incoming connections will break a lot of things so use with caution.

Comment: and does it possible to block all incoming connections under android?

Comment: Sure. It just may break things.

Comment: and how can I do this? Block all incomming conections?

Comment: You really should read at least an iptables howto before trying to do this. You have already blocked them, just the add rule I wrote above to allow already established connections.

Comment: I found another wy to do the same thing. It is possible just to drop all of SYN packets. Something like that : `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP`

Comment: There are some subtle differences between `--syn` and `--state ESTABLISHED`, but should also work.